# BASH - Prompt paste multiple lines of input save to file

Tags: bash, prompt

I have a script that asks my users for some input. name, id, location etc

Is it possible for them to paste multiple lines of data into a prompt input and have that saved to a file ?

```
echo -e "Please enter the details:"
read data
# Do something... and save to file..
```

They will be pasting data similar to :

`67jhub7uy86b8tib8,North
485734957934fsdfs,East
7676bh7h87g87bibi,East
89798kfhg8r9t8494,South
98onoulj5005555tr,West`

There could be one line, there might be 50 lines..

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `read`:

```
read -rp 'Please enter the details: ' -d $'\04' data
```

and press `ctrl-D` on terminal after entering your multiline data.

Check content of `data` variable by using

```
declare -p data
```

Comment: Thanks but will ctrl-d quit me out of my script ?

Comment: No that shouldn't be happening. `ctrl-D` only stops current `read` command. You can put `date`, `pwd` etc commands after this `read` and you see output of those.

Comment: OK Thanks.. I'll test this again and report back :)

Comment: Thanks for this.. is there a way to add a new line so the first value is below the prompt not on the same line  ?

Comment: Yes just put an empty `echo` just below this `read` command line.